# Efficient algorithms to perform Market Basket Analysis

Tags: python, sql, performance, apriori, market-basket-analysis

I want to perform Market Basket Analysis (or Association Analysis) on retail ecommerce dataset.

The problem I am facing is the huge data size of 3.3 million transactions in a single month. I cannot cut down the transactions as I may miss some products. Provided below the structure of the data:

*Order_ID = Unique transaction identifier*

*Customer_ID = Identifier of the customer who placed the order*

*Product_ID = List of all the products the customer has purchased*

*Date = Date on which the sale has happened*

When I feed this data to the #apriori algorithm in Python, my system cannot handle the huge memory requirements to run. It can run with just 100K transactions. I have 16gb RAM.

Any help in **suggesting a better** (and faster) algorithm is much appreciated.

I can use SQL as well to sort out data size issues, but I will get only 1 Antecedent --> 1 Consequent rule. Is there a way to get **multiset rules** such as {A,B,C} --> {D,E} i.e, If a customer purchases products A, B and C, then there is a high chance to purchase products D and E.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For a huge data size try [FP Growth](https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/frequent_patterns/fpgrowth/), as it is an [improvement](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/fp-growth-algorithm-data-mining/) to the Apriori method.
It also only loop data twice when compared to Apriori.

```
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import fpgrowth
```

Then just change:

```
apriori(df, min_support=0.6)
```

To

```
fpgrowth(df, min_support=0.6)
```

There also an research that compare each algorithm, for memory issue I recommend :
[Evaluation of Apriori, FP growth and Eclat association rule miningalgorithms](https://sciencescholar.us/journal/index.php/ijhs/article/view/6729) or
[Comparing the Performance of Frequent Pattern Mining Algorithms](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/272864559_Comparing_the_Performance_of_Frequent_Pattern_Mining_Algorithms).